# Tried to upload a project to Heroku, Heroku said my binstubs are mangled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku

I am unable to upload a project to Heroku, after speaking to their support they have told me the following:

> Your binstubs are still messed up
>
> "#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.3 APP_PATH =
>   File.expand_path('../config/application', **dir**) require_relative
>   '../config/boot'  require 'rails/commands'"
>
> You need that to say "#!/usr/bin/env ruby On the top line."
>
> It looks like you may have a bad install of ruby. I recommend using
>   chruby and ruby-install to manage multiple ruby installations locally.
>   You can manually fix it in all of your bin/* files but you should also
>   probably put in some work to figure out what is wrong on your system
>   that generated those lines in the first place.

What steps should I take next to correct this. I am not well versed with binstubs and am unsure how to proceed or what caused my binstubs to get messed up originally. I haven't had any issues with Ruby so far and im running ruby

```
luis@luis-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/mls2$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

> Issue resolved using rbenv. Started a new rails app and copied the
>   binstubs of the new app into my existing app and it corrected the
>   issue and app is posted to Heroku.

Comment: have you tried their recommendation, and if so, what happened? Keep in mind that the binstub ("shebang") line is not ruby code, it's shell, so you can't use File.expand_path or anything

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I just got the message today, what I am really wondering is How this happened and what I can do to prevent it if it happens again in the future. I have never had any issues with Ruby so far. I have been suing Ruby for almost a year now.

Comment: Read up on what a shebang is, e.g. [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: Issue Resolved. So I was able to correct the Binstubs in the Rails Directory. I also used rbenv to manage version of Ruby for the future after speaking to a friend of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Issue resolved using rbenv. Started a new rails app and copied the
>   binstubs of the new app into my existing app and it corrected the
>   issue and app is posted to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put file `.ruby-version` to root project folder with content:

```
ruby 2.3.1
```

or your ruby version. good luck!